# Android Button Not Working

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I have built an app that reads a SQLite database to display a school timetable but my buttons are not working; please, could someone have a look at the code and see if they can fix it? The code is available here: https://github.com/Ottermad/YourTimetable. Any help is welcome.

Comment: No one will read that code to search for... what? copy the relevant code (the db class, the button click listener, the layout that contains it, ...) into your question, if you want it answered. Don't be lazy! By the way... welcome to SO.

Comment: it'l be good if you 1. Throw some light on the exact problem - eg. "buttons are not working" - that way "SO also not working" and 2. Reasonably, Take some effort, if not in debugging, then better to paste the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

For once,

by the look of it,
your `activty_main.xml` layout has button1 and button2 id(s) assigned twice. Change name of either set of id.
On why you should/shoudn't do that, check:
http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-layout-and-id-attribute/
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#id